# Can I generate referral URLs with the full question title?

Tags: feature-request, support, hyperlinks, referrals

When I want to share a question, I can either share a link with the full question title:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290101/could-match-start0-ever-return-1-in-python
```

Or I can use a shortened referral link with my user id that [gets tracked for badges](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/q/75290101/3357935
```

Let's say I want to keep the question title for context without giving up badge progression. I can add my user id to the full URL after the question title, but I don't know if visits with this link are tracked for badge progress.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290101/could-match-start0-ever-return-1-in-python/3357935
```

Is it possible to generate a question URL that includes the full question title and also works for badge tracking?

Comment: SO doesn't object to throwing the title _after_ the user ID, either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290101/176071/could-match-start0-ever-return-1-in-python/ ... But again, not sure if that works for tracking.

Comment: Initially, I thought this was referring to being able to generate "share" text that included the post title formatted as a link to the post using Markdown. (Which would also be useful.)

Answer (score 5):

What you could do is assign the question title to a random parameter like this: `https://stackoverflow.com/q/75290101/3357935?title=could-match-start0-ever-return-1-in-python`. As a bonus, you can even retain the original formatting; the link `https://stackoverflow.com/q/75290101/3357935?title=Could+Match.start(0)+ever+return+-1+in+Python?` works as well. (Depending on where/how you post the link, it might even work with spaces instead of `+` signs.)